# Why GMT and UTC timezones don't have same rules

Tags: java, timezone

Why does below line print false? i think it should print true.

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+5:30").hasSameRules(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30")
```

Comment: Note UTC has leap seconds which Java doesn't support so really it's just GMT.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is in the [JavaDoc of TimeZone#getTimeZone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone-java.lang.String-):

> the ID for a TimeZone, either an abbreviation such as "PST", a full name such as "America/Los_Angeles", or a custom ID such as "GMT-8:00"
>
> **Returns**:
>   the specified TimeZone, or the GMT zone if the given ID cannot be understood.

And (from the [class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html))

> [...] The syntax of a custom time zone ID is:

```
  CustomID:
     GMT Sign Hours : Minutes
     GMT Sign Hours Minutes
     GMT Sign Hours
```

The ID `"UTC+5:30"` is not a valid TimeZone ID (as per the specification of the method/class) and is interpreted as "GMT" zone, which is clearly distinct from the "GMT+5:30" zone.

Comment: Bit of a weird design choice to return GMT for invalid input. An exception or `null` may have been better as it lets the caller decide what to do in this case.

Comment: You are certainly correct, @Thilo. In recognition of the bad design of `TimeZone` on this point its modern replacement `ZoneId` does throw an exception in this case. I warmly recommend using [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) over the old date and time classes including `TimeZone`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are located in India, you should use

```
    ZoneId india = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
```

Two messages:

1. The `TimeZone` class has design problems and is long outdated. The same goes for its friends like `Calender` and `SimpleDateFormat`. So don’t use them. Instead use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Its replacement for `TimeZone` is the `ZoneId` class (and `ZoneOffset` for an offset from UTC, but don’t use that as a time zone, it isn’t one, see the next item).
2. Don’t use an offset from either UTC or GMT as a time zone. It works in your particular case, of course, but it may leave the reader wondering why you chose +05:30, which `Asia/Kolkata` clearly conveys. Also `Asia/Kolkata` is future-proof in case at some point in time the politicians change the UTC offset for India or introduce summer time (DST). While this is unlikely for India, it happens all the time in other places in the world, so It’s better to make it a habit to use the *region/city* format always.

For just one of the many design advantages of the modern API, try the modern version of your code:

```
    ZoneId.of("UTC+5:30").getRules().equals(ZoneId.of("GMT+5:30").getRules())
```

This throws: `java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid ID for offset-based ZoneId: UTC+5:30`. Now you know from the outset what’s wrong: `UTC+5:30` is not a valid time zone ID.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.